# IBM Cognos Business Intelligence 10.1.1. with IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, business-intelligence, cognos

I have installed IBM Cognos 10.1.1 and i would use the Internet Explorere 11.

Is that possible ? Is it compatible ?

Comment: Check the [supported software](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27021368).

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use IE11. For your reference kindly check this link,under Supported Software tab look for the Web Browser category.

[IE 11 Compatibility](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1267644462529&osPlatform=Windows#sw-17)

Hope this helps.